# Use :not with :first-of-type or :first-child

Tags: css

How can I select the **first dom** with class "a" but without "b"?

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="a b"></div>
    <div class="a b"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a b"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

This is my way... but I don't want to use this way...

```
.group {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.group .a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 12px;
}
.group .a:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.group .a:not(.b) {
  background-color: #333;
}
.group .a:not(.b) ~ .a {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```